# Fluent UI ComboBox allowFreeform

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have issues with a controlled [ComboBox](https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/fluentui#/controls/web/combobox) in fluentui from ms.
I not been able to insert my own text, after insert and press enter the text disappears.
The option selection works without problems.

Here a codepen: https://codepen.io/verhext/pen/jOrKOPe

```
 <ComboBox
    componentRef={comboBoxRef}
    defaultValue={selectedKey}
    selectedKey={selectedKey}
    label="Basic ComboBox"
    allowFreeform
    autoComplete="on"
    options={comboBoxBasicOptions}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my code.
Thank you!

Comment: When you start typing "Opt..." component suggest an item to select. Otherwise you cant select something that suggestion list doesn't include.

Comment: Okay, but how handle Microsoft Teams that case. There is a ComboBox  for calendar event start and end time and I'm able to insert a time in format hh:mm or select one of the DropDown Options.

Comment: Microsoft Teams uses react-northstar library. https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.51.2/quick-start

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Combobox doesn't allow you to select any text value. allowFreeForm prop means that you can use manual search to select items.

Comment: `allowFreeInput` restricts input to only matching options. `allowFreeform` allows user to input any value without restricting to provided options. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/combobox

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way... Basically onChange event has four parameters.. "value" contains the typed in text. "selectedOption" would be undefined when there was no matching key/value.
You can use "text" property to assign the value back to the control.

```
private onComboBoxChange = (selectedOption: any, value: string): void => {
    let v = value;
    if (selectedOption) {
        v = selectedOption.key;
    }
    this.props.onStateChange(v);
} 

<ComboBox allowFreeform={true} autoComplete={'on'}
          options={this.props.options} 
          onChange={(e, selectedOption, i, value) => { this.onComboBoxChange(selectedOption, value); }}                            
          text={<value>} />
```